# CSS-jquery Change background swatch on clicking the swatch icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like the page background to change when I click on a particular swatch. My jquery code does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

```js
$(".black swatch").click(function() {
  $("body").addClass("black");
});
```

```css
.swatch {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatches">
  <div class="black swatch"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of $(".black swatch") try $(".black.swatch")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it like this? it's because you are clicking the .swatch div only which then runs the script to add the class.

```js
$(".swatch").click(function() {
  $("body").addClass("black");
});
```

```css
.swatch {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatches">
  <div class="black swatch"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `.swatch` is not a child element of `.black` at

```
$(".black swatch")
```

also missing `.` at `swatch`, though this would not effect previous issue.

If you have multiple `.swatch` elements at `html` and `.swatch` elements only have two `className`s you could replace `swatch` `className` to set `className` at `body`

```
$(".swatch").click(function() {
  $("body").addClass(this.className.replace(/swatch/, "").trim());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the class `swatch`

[Working JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/hirasabudo/edit?html,css,js,output)